# Trying to modify a matrix of unknown size in matlab with certain restrictions

Tags: loops, matlab, vectorization

Basically no for/while loops or if statements. Therefore I assume the colon operator is suppose to be used.

I'm new to Matlab and have basically used for loops in one way or another to accomplish virtually everything and can't find any online resources to help so a quick answer is greatly appreciated.

Essentially the goal is to create and return a new matrix based off an inputted matrix. The new matrix contains only the even indexed elements of the original so a 4x4 matrix would return a 2x2 and a 5x5 would also return a 2x2 because anything in the 5th row or column couldn't have both an even column and row.

My code:

```
function [A] = myFunction(M)
[x y] = size(M);

for a = 2:2:x
    for b = 2:2:y
        A(a/2, b/2) = M(a,b);
    end
end
end
```

Which works but I am trying to understand how to do it without the for loops and using the colon operator so I can do that in other applications as well where it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

very simple

```
A = M(2:2:end, 2:2:end);
```

Read about [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) for more information and details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the link.